# Getting the value of input tag in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the value of my input upon a click of the button.
I am able to get the value of text box but not for drop down list and number box (input type=number).

How should I go about doing it?

Below is my code:

```
          <div class=accountMain>
            <div align=left>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Code:</td>
                    <td>EX00001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Name:</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=productName value=$productName></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=productDesc value=$productDesc></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Price: SGD$</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=unitPrice value=$unitPrice></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity Available:</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=qty value=$qty></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Size <br>
                    (Only applicable for T-Shirt):</td>
                    <td><select>
                    <option value=N>NIL</option>
                    <option value=S>S</option>
                    <option value=M>M</option>
                    <option value=L>L</option>
                    <option value=XL>XL</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Product Image:</td>
                    <td><input type=file name=imgfile></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Category: Exclusive</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type=submit name=insert value=Insert></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </div>

    </td>
    </tr>


    </div>



 echo("<tr><td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><font style=title><b>In Stock : ".$row["qty"]."</b></br></br></br></br>
                        <b><form>Purchase Qty : <input type=number name=qty min=1 max=5></form></b></br></br>
                        </br></font></td>

                        </tr>");

                echo("<tr><td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href=shoppingbag.php><img src=images/addToCartBtn.png width=150></a></td></tr>");
```

Comment: that's the html, where is the php?

Answer (score 1):

your `<select>` requires a name attribute

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
<select>
    <option value=N>NIL</option>
    <option value=S>S</option>
    <option value=M>M</option>
    <option value=L>L</option>
    <option value=XL>XL</option>
</select>
```

To:

```
<select name="size">
    <option value=N>NIL</option>
    <option value=S>S</option>
    <option value=M>M</option>
    <option value=L>L</option>
    <option value=XL>XL</option>
</select>
```

And get it using:

```
<?php $_POST["size"]; ?>
```

Comment: Can I check with you what about the input type number? I even tried to get by elementid but dont work

Comment: `<input type="number" />` is supported only in webkit based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is also marked under PHP, I presume you want to send these values to a PHP page?

If so, unless you are submitting the values dynamically (through script), you'll want to wrap the input and select elements in `<form>` opening and closing tags. Then you can set the method attribute (*post,put,get,delete*) and the action attribute (*the path to the PHP page to process the values*).

```
<form method="post" action="path-to/my-php-page.php">
...
</form>
```

HINT: The way your HTML is structured, you may want to wrap the whole of the innermost table with the form tag.